# Detecting new line while typing in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i am typing in a text area, how can i detect whether the current word i am typing is the first word in the newline.
I just want to find whether my current text is the new line of the text area

Is there any possibility to detect this using jquery or javascript?

Comment: Describe detect? Why and in what context?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti I think it's not duplicate, OP wants to detect when the number of characters is greater than the width of the textarea

Answer (score 1):

The textarea element has an attribute named `cols`. Given a text area element:

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="ta" rows="10" cols="50">Write something here</textarea>
```

you can check with an event listener (on keypress, change... whatever fits your needings) if the number of characters is larger than the number of columns:

```js
const textArea=document.getElementById("ta");
textArea.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  const lines = ta.value.split(/\n/);
  let numberOfLines = lines.length;
  document.getElementById("new-lines").innerHTML = numberOfLines;
  for (line of lines) {
    if (line.length > ta.cols) { numberOfLines++; }
  }
  document.getElementById("total-lines").innerHTML = numberOfLines;
  
});
```

```html
<textarea name="textarea" id="ta" rows="10" cols="50">Write something here</textarea>
<p>New lines (carrier return)<span id="new-lines"></span> </p>
<p>Total lines: <span id="total-lines"></span> </p>
```

##### Note: this only works with monospaced fonts

Comment: Each characters have the same size ?

Comment: Usually text areas show text using monospaced fonts

Comment: Weird solution to force using a typo for this problem.